# How Can I add a menu to the theme from withen the function.php file

Tags: functions, menus

I have the following code I'm trying to automatically add a menu to a theme via overriding a function. So I won't have to edit the theme file

However the menu is being outputted at the top of the page and on every page instead of only in its given location.

```
 /*******************************
     MENUS SUPPORT
    ********************************/
    if ( function_exists( 'wp_nav_menu' ) ){
        if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
            add_theme_support('nav-menus');

            function register_cbx_menus() {
                register_nav_menus(
                    array(
                        //'primary_navigation' => __( 'Main Menu'),
                        'legal_footer_navigation' => __( 'Legal Footer Menu'),
                        'echo'            => 0,
                    )
                );
            }
            add_action( 'init', 'register_cbx_menus' );
        }
    }

    //******************************************************
    //Function to override default footer credits
    //*******************************************************
    if ( !function_exists('ci_theme_footer_credits') ) {  
       function ci_theme_footer_credits() {

         // Get blog/site name
         $cbx_blogame = get_bloginfo( 'name'); 

         //$cbx_footernav = ;

         //Output new footer content
         return '<div class="cbx-footer-nav">
            &copy; '.date('Y').'&nbsp;'. $cbx_blogname .'&nbsp;'.'All rights reserved. '.wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'legal_footer_navigation' ) ).'</div> '
         .'<div class="cbx-poweredby">Powered by <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" title="example.com">example.com</a></div>';
       }    //End function

     } //End function
```

How can I modify the above code to properly add the menu to a theme via the fucntion.php file without having to edit the theme file to add

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'legal_footer_navigation' ));
```

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you edit the theme file or create a child theme?

Comment: because I would have edit 30+ themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current call to `wp_nav_menu()` may be echoing the menu when the code is seen and not returning it in the function.

Try this call:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'legal_footer_navigation',
    'echo'           => false,
) );
```

If that works, you can also probably remove the echo parameter from the `register_nav_menus()` call.

Comment: Thanks it works the only issue is using return makes the menu appear in front of everything else as oppose to exactly where I want it

Comment: You may be able to use the CSS `z-index` property to layer it behind other elements. Or you could get more help by asking a new question with a link to your test page. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index